# Can I tell PyCharm that a function argument is a Django template path to enable autocomplete?

Tags: django, autocomplete, pycharm

In Pycharm, template paths used in built-in Django functionality which will eventually be used as the argument to `resolve_template` (such as the `template_name` property on `TemplateView` or arguments to the `include` template tag) are subject to autocomplete suggestions and value warnings using the Django template lookup syntax.

I have a custom function whose signature includes a template name. Is there a way to annotate this function such that PyCharm will provide the same template directory autocomplete suggestions for the template name argument in uses of this custom function, like it provides for built-in template name values?

Answer (score 0):

I have a silly workaround:
If you name your function "render" and have at least 2 parameters, it will autocomplete the template name in the second parameter, so I think they just hardcoded a rule saying "if a function is called render, autocomplete template paths in the second parameter". It does not have to be django.shortcuts.render.

So you could use:

```
def render(a, b):
    return b

template_name = render(..., "template path autocompletion is invoked here")
```